# How do I make my application Integrated Loginable?

Tags: c#, security

I am always doing the following Login module:

1. Create a table with Username and Password
2. Login by checking the user table.

So how do I use integrated Login just like the application like Sql Server? I don't mean by passing a connection string, I mean it will check the credential of my application without putting any username and password.

Thanks

EDIT:

I don't mean the SQL Server integrated Login, I mean my application's integrated login, is it possible?

For example, my application will read the AD's name and compare to the current username, then I don't need the user to type in a password for my application.

I am not sure how do I do that and where to start, since if I search Integrated Login, 99.9% of the results from Google will give me the connection string, which I am not looking for that.

Comment: The application will run under the context of the user who started the process.  I.E. if domain\joe.blogs starts the program in his login session the program will use his credentials.  It works this way so you don't have to worry about authentication yourself.

Comment: However, if domain\joe.blogs wanted to run the application as domain\john.doe then he'd either have to log into the workstation as john.doe, perform a "runas" as john.doe or use impersonation as john.doe.  Which of these scenarios matches what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It will depends on who the user login as, or run as, not who started the process.
So the user who use my application must be the person who logged on to that domain on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

**[This answer assumes that you're on an Active Directory domain]**

Are you using active directory windows authentication?  If this is the case you can use the integrated security option in the connection string.

Here's an example connection string using integrated security:

```
"Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=db name;Integrated Security=True"
```

This would reduce the complexity allowing you to forget about having to ask the user for a username and password because it'll pick up the windows credentials that they've logged into the workstation with.

Edit:

If the application is a website then you'll need to set the SQL server as "trusted for delegation" in active directory (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905162(SQL.80).aspx).  This will allow the webserver to delegate the user's windows login credentials to the SQL server.  If you don't do this then the SQL connection will be anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your application will be running with Active Directory on the local network I think there are a few options, depending on how do you want to implement authorization.

If you want/need to do authorization with some custom rules/logic then the first thing you need is to determine who ran the application:

- [Environment.UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx) in conjunction with [Environment.UserDomainName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx) will give you enough information;
- Alternatively (and more secure) you have use the following code snippet:

  ```
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(
      System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
  var identity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
  ```

From the `identity` you can extract [Security Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier) which is designed to be globally unique. (But not that pretty as domain\username pair.)

After getting current user's name you can apply whatever authorization rules you want.